# reemplazar valor de fila por el de otra fila si cumple condición en r

Tags: r

tengo un data frame con las columnas "fecha", "envíos", "feriados". la columna de los feriados, toma valor 1 si es feriado y valor 0 si no lo es

```
|   fecha  |envios|feriado|
|:---------|:----:|------:|
|2021-02-09|  362 |   0   |
|2021-02-10|  521 |   0   |
|2021-02-11|  412 |   0   |
|2021-02-12|  467 |   0   |
|2021-02-13|  314 |   0   |
|2021-02-14|  531 |   0   |
|2021-02-15|  246 |   0   |
|2021-02-16|  12  |   1   |
```

si es feriado, como el 2021-02-16, necesito que esa fila tome el valor de la fila de 7 dias antes, del 2021-02-09

intenté

`datos_envios$envios = ifelse(datos_envios$feriado == "1", select(-7), datos_envios$envios)`

pero no funciona

Answer (score 0):

## Opción simple (y peligrosa)

Si tienes **absoluta seguridad** de que la serie de tiempo está completa (nunca se salta un día) y está perfectamente ordenada entonces esta alternativa muy simple te podría servir.

```
#recreo los datos
read.table(text = 
"fecha envios feriado
2021-02-09 362 0
2021-02-10 521 0
2021-02-11 412 0
2021-02-12 467 0
2021-02-13 314 0
2021-02-14 531 0
2021-02-15 246 0
2021-02-16 12  1", header = T) -> fechas

library(tidyverse)

fechas %>% 
  mutate(envios = ifelse(feriado == 1, lag(envios, 7), envios))
```

Menciono lo de la serie de tiempo completa y ordenada porque lo que hace es buscar el valor de `envios` 7 filas más arriba. Para que 7 filas sean 7 días (una semana) necesitas que se den esas condiciones.

## Opción segura (y complicada)

Una opción más segura, pero bastante más complicada sería:

```
#Creo unos datos con la serie de tiempo discontínua
read.table(text = 
"fecha envios feriado
2021-02-09 362 0
2021-02-10 521 0
2021-02-11 412 0
2021-02-12 467 0
2021-02-13 314 0
2021-02-14 531 0
2021-02-15 246 0
2021-02-16 12  1
2021-03-16 100 1", header = T) -> fechas_picantes

library(lubridate)
fechas_picantes %>% 
  mutate(fecha = ymd(fecha)) -> fechas_picantes

fechas_picantes %>% 
  mutate(semana_anterior = fecha - weeks(1)) %>%
  left_join(fechas_picantes, by = c("semana_anterior" = "fecha")) %>% 
  mutate(envios = ifelse(feriado.x == 1, envios.y, envios.x)) %>% 
  select(fecha, envios, feriado = feriado.x)
```

Es más segura porque lo que hace es:

1. Computar `semana_anterior` que es la fecha una semana anterior a `fecha`
2. Empatar con el join la fecha de la semana anterior con los envíos de la semana anterior.
3. Si fue feriado toma el valor de envíos de la semana anterior, si no se queda con el valor que ya estaba.

Creo que es más segura porque si hay saltos en la serie no va a fallar: va a buscar una semana anterior (aunque falten uno o más días en el medio) y si no la encuentra regresar `NA`, haciendo explícito el problema.

Trabajar con fechas es bastante complicado, creo que lo mejor es usar siempre que se pueda los atributos de la clase `Date` para asegurar las cosas. Resuelve intrínsecamente los problemas recurrentes como años bisiestos, series imcompletas, etc.